# PDO establishing connection to Azure PostgreSQL is very slow

Tags: php, postgresql, azure, pdo, kubernetes

I have PHP application running as a Docker container based on Alpine Linux inside Kubernetes. Everything went well until I tried removing container with test database and replacing it with [Azure PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/cs-cz/services/postgresql/). This led to significant latency increase from under 250ms to above 1500ms.

According to profiler most time is spent in [PDO constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) which is establishing connection to database. **The SQL queries themselves, after connection was established, then run in about 20ms.**

- **I tried using IP instead of address and it was still slow.**
- I tried connecting from container using psql and it was slow (see full command below)
- I tried DNS resolution using [bind-tools](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/bind-tools) and it was fast.
- Database runs in same region as Kubernetes nodes, tried even same resource group, different network settings and nothing helped.
- I tried requiring/disabling SSL mode on both client and server
- I tried repeatedly running 'select 1' inside an already established connection and it was fast (average 1.2ms, median 0.9ms) (see full query below)

What can cause such a latency? 
How can I further debug/investigate this issue?

---

psql command used to try connection:

```
psql "sslmode=disable host=host dbname=postgres user=user@host.postgres.database.azure.com password=password" -c "select 1"
```

---

Query speed

```
\timing 
SELECT;
\watch 1
```

Comment: Did you try connecting from the Kubernetes pod to the postgres db?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it and it was slow (600ms+)

Comment: Where is you Kubernetes cluster? Azure? What region?

Comment: Both cluster and database are in the same region West US 2. Database is in the same resource group as nodes.

Comment: It sounds like you have some rate-limiting between your kubernetes nodes and PostgreSQL. You can open a support ticket with your cloud provider to check.

Comment: Already opened a ticket, nothing useful yet. Would rate-limiting affect only connection creation or network latency in general? I tried running 'select 1' in a loop inside already established connection and it was fast.  (updated post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell it is caused by Azure specific authentication on top of PostgreSQL. Unfortunately Azure support was not able to help from their side.

Using connection pool ([PgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/)) solves this problem. It is another piece of infrastructure we have to maintain (docker file, config/secret management, etc.), which we hoped to outsource to cloud provider.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you have any sources for the latency due to how Azure decided to secure pg?

Comment: No, it is a conclusion based solely on my observations. I might be completely wrong.

Comment: Even with python Django, the database is extremely slow, Azure needs to handle this